# A line of code that works in linux terminal does not work when in a bash script

Tags: bash

This line of code

```
${#$(echo xla | egrep "^[aeiouAEIOU]")}
```

in the terminal when passed as a parameter to `echo` returns the length of the result of the stream, but when i put it in my script it returns a `bad substitution` error. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: What are you using for an interactive shell?

Comment: This is just _tinkering_. Nothing reliable

Comment: `echo xla | egrep '^[aeiouAEIOU]' | wc -c`?

Comment: This gives +1 @Fravadona.

Comment: Define your meaning of **linux terminal**. In common terminology, a terminal is a device or program which hosts a shell - in Linux for instance xterm -, and what matters is not so much which terminal application you use, but which shell you run in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reliable way:

```
$ x=$(grep -E "^[xaeiouAEIOU]" <<< xla)
$ echo "$x"
xla
$ echo "${#x}"
3
```

`egrep` is now deprecated, in favor of `grep -E`